# Need way to know when my Django Model instances are queried

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add a Framework to my Django Models that will allow for my model instances to Expire. I will have a timed task that will walk through the expirable Models and delete the expired instances.

I have different types of expirations that I want to do. The first one is a basic TimeDeltaExpiry which will expire the instances after a timedelta from the time the instance was last Saved. The expiry gets updated when the instance is saved.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expiry = self.expiry.datetime + timedelta(minutes=2)
        super(TimeDeltaExpiry, self).save()
```

The second one is a RefreshableTimeDeltaExpiry that should have the expiry updated every time the instance gets queried. Not sure if this is even possible, but I was looking for a method or feature that would allow me to capture when the instance is referenced. There also is the concern that when my purging task runs, that it would also be referencing the instance and update the expiry, which I of course would not want to have happen.

Is there a technique that might allow me to do what I want?

Here is my untested code so far

```
class ExpiryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(expiry__lt=Now()), output_field=BooleanField())
        )


class ExpiryBase(models.Model):
    expiry = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = ExpiryManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TimeDeltaExpiry(ExpiryBase):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expiry = self.expiry.datetime + timedelta(minutes=2)
        super(TimeDeltaExpiry, self).save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class RefreshableTimeDeltaExpiry(TimeDeltaExpiry):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```